# CoffeeScript with ERB error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb

I am trying to pre-open a div in a accordion. I am setting an instance variable `@expanded_section` in the corresponding controller. And I am trying to use that value in the `active` parameter of the jQuery-UI accordion like this using erb on my coffeescript file in the `assets/javascripts` folder

```
$( ".sections" ).accordion({
  active: <%=@expanded_section%>,
  header: "h4",
  collapsible: true,
  heightStyle: "content"  }).sortable({
  axis: "y",
  handle: "h4",
  update: ->
    $.post($(this).data('update'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  })
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 60: Unexpected ','
```

(in /home/steve/dev/rails/Survey/app/assets/javascripts/surveyys.js.coffee.erb)

`line 60` is `active: <%=@expanded_section%>,`

If I do a `to_i` call on `@expanded_section` it renders `active:0`.

But when I print the value of `@expanded_section` to the console from the controller it prints the proper expected value.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything under `assets/` will be processed *before* your controllers run. This means that `@expanded_section` won't come from your controller, it will come from whatever `self` is when the assets are being compiled so it, like all instance variables, will be created on first access and will be `nil`. The result is that CoffeeScript will see this:

```
$( ".sections" ).accordion({
  active: ,
```

and that's a syntax error.

One easy thing you could do is to set a global JavaScript variable in your view's HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.expanded_section = <%= @expanded_section %>;
</script>
```

and then your asset script can look in `window`:

```
$( ".sections" ).accordion({
  active: window.expanded_section,
```

You'll probably want to hide that in a custom namespace to avoid conflicts with existing `window` properties but the overall structure will be the same. That little `window.expanded_section = ...` but might even go in your layout if it is part of every page.

Comment: How do I do the window.expanded_section in haml?

Comment: @stevanity: Sorry, no idea, not a HAML guy. A bit of Googling should help.

Comment: Okay np :) I used a javascript filter. Anyway. in my js file I get `window.expanded_section` just like that :(

Comment: Where are you getting "`window.expanded_section` just like that"? In the compiled version of the CoffeeScript? That should be fine, the `window.expanded_section` should be resolved in the browser after `expanded_section` has been assigned (in JavaScript) the value you want it to have.

Comment: No it came in the final js :( ok. I scrapped this solution and I rendered the value in a hidden div in the HTML and I accessed the value from coffeescript. like this: `expanded_section=$('#expanded_section').html()' and then in the accordion call  `active: expanded_section,`. But in the final js (not coffee as I removed erb), I get active: expanded_section, just like that!